# How to make a Joomla! component cross-compatible (J2.5 - J3.x)

Tags: development, extensions, recommended-practices

When developing a Joomla! 3.x component, how do you make it backwards compatible with Joomla! 2.5?

Comment: The question is still very broad. As I'm sure you are aware, there can be lots of nuances and fringe issues that could affect your component that many other people would never face. Is there a specific aspect of making a component work on both J2.5 and J3 that you are struggling with? Is there things that you have tried that feel like they should work but haven't worked for you?

Comment: I appreciate your question. We have also faced this issue and we didn't want to manage multiple component for multiple Joomla versions. So we have created a wrapper which are handle multiple Joomla compatibility. Our all component extends from this wrapper. We are treat it as Rapid Application Development framework for Joomla. Right-now, its not so mature and not well documented that we will market it, but It's good solution. :)  You can see https://github.com/readybytes/rbframework

Comment: @Adam - this is a complex topic, but covered very well in Learning Joomla! 3 Extensions, 3rd Ed. by Tim Plummer http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Joomla-Extension-Development-Third-Edition/dp/1782168370

Comment: Facing the same question a couple of year ago, and after reviewing several frameworks, I've choosed FoF as a solution to J! 2.5/3 compatibility. https://github.com/akeeba/fof

Comment: It's not actually a problem I currently face but it would have been interesting to see how other people go about it and if there's any recommended practices.

Answer (score 2):

There cannot be a clear answer, a lot depend from what kind of the extension you do.

Main development for j3.x, and time to time test on j2.5 whether there no faults and the extension works as expected - for most cases should be good solution.